# How to write this kind of documentation easily?

Tags: text, ascii, ascii-art

I love pure ascii text documentation, like this one:
http://www.catonmat.net/download/sed.stream.editor.cheat.sheet.txt

But I don't know how to write it easily. There are lots of tables in it. Anyone can explain it please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Emacs Table Mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode (http://table.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.multieditsoftware.com/ME2008.php
As far as I remember there're such feature.